# MongoDB Cursor Timeout on Update

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm currently writing a PHP script to compile data from a number of different CSVs and import the combined document into Mongo. During this process, I'm running into an error with my cursor timing out during an update. Seen here (with included var_dump() for $line and $voterId):

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'MongoCursorTimeoutException' with message 'localhost:27017: Read timed out after reading 0 bytes, waited for 30.000000 seconds' in /Users/georgeyates/Projects/cerebro-jobs/cavers-parse-phone.php:40
Stack trace:
#0 cavers-parse-phone.php(40): MongoCollection->update(Array, Array)
#1 {main}
  thrown in cavers-parse-phone.php on line 40

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoCursorTimeoutException' with message 'localhost:27017: Read timed out after reading 0 bytes, waited for 30.000000 seconds' in /Users/georgeyates/Projects/cerebro-jobs/cavers-parse-phone.php:40
Stack trace:
#0 cavers-parse-phone.php(40): MongoCollection->update(Array, Array)
#1 {main}
  thrown in cavers-parse-phone.php on line 40
```

The "Id" field in the search criteria of the update is indexed and finds executed through the Mongo console or PHP are sub-second. Also if I run the update manually through the Mongo console there are no problems and it runs sub-second. Here's my PHP code, $voterId, and $line are both a valid string and array respectively:

```
$db->Voters->update(array(
    array(
        "Id" => $voterId
    )
),
array(
    '$push' => array(
        "PhoneCalls" => $line
    )
));
```

Currently during development I've got the whole process running locally on my machine. Interestingly enough, when I exit out of the mongod process, I see the query in the log dumped during the exit process which indicates to me that there's a problem with the update. You can see a single server session log from startup to exit with only that single update query running below:

```
Tue Jan  7 16:44:53.266 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=4963 port=27017 dbpath=/usr/local/var/mongodb 64-bit host=Georges-MacBook-Pro.local
Tue Jan  7 16:44:53.266 [initandlisten] 
Tue Jan  7 16:44:53.266 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
Tue Jan  7 16:44:53.266 [initandlisten] db version v2.4.8
Tue Jan  7 16:44:53.266 [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion
Tue Jan  7 16:44:53.266 [initandlisten] build info: Darwin Georges-MacBook-Pro.local 13.0.2 Darwin Kernel Version 13.0.2: Sun Sep 29 19:38:57 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2422.75.4~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Tue Jan  7 16:44:53.266 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
Tue Jan  7 16:44:53.266 [initandlisten] options: { bind_ip: "127.0.0.1", config: "/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf", dbpath: "/usr/local/var/mongodb", logappend: "true", logpath: "/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log" }
Tue Jan  7 16:44:53.268 [initandlisten] journal dir=/usr/local/var/mongodb/journal
Tue Jan  7 16:44:53.268 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
Tue Jan  7 16:44:53.474 [websvr] admin web console waiting for connections on port 28017
Tue Jan  7 16:44:53.474 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
Tue Jan  7 16:45:23.839 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:63253 #1 (1 connection now open)
Tue Jan  7 16:45:57.638 [signalProcessingThread] got signal 2 (Interrupt: 2), will terminate after current cmd ends
Tue Jan  7 16:45:57.640 [signalProcessingThread] now exiting
Tue Jan  7 16:45:57.640 dbexit: 
Tue Jan  7 16:45:57.640 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Tue Jan  7 16:45:57.640 [signalProcessingThread] closing listening socket: 9
Tue Jan  7 16:45:57.640 [conn1] update cavers-import.Voters query: { 0: { Id: "a0Qd0000001kMRwEAM" } } update: { $push: { PhoneCalls: [ "a0ed0000000p75wAAA", "005d00000010pc9AAA", "0", "Phone- 000000000", "2012-09-21 19:16:30", "005d00000010pc9AAA", "2012-09-21 19:16:30", "005d00000010pc9AAA", "2013-01-05 17:18:54", "", "", "", "Sample Question Text appears here !", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "", "", "", "Undecided", "Undecided", "Undecided", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "0", "0", "0", "a0Qd0000001kMRwEAM", "Favorable", "House 55 > 65, VP3-7", "", "", "", "", "", "" ] } } nscanned:816378 keyUpdates:0 exception: interrupted at shutdown code:11600 numYields: 7907 locks(micros) w:62634071 33653ms
Tue Jan  7 16:45:57.640 [signalProcessingThread] closing listening socket: 10
Tue Jan  7 16:45:57.640 [signalProcessingThread] closing listening socket: 11
Tue Jan  7 16:45:57.640 [signalProcessingThread] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
Tue Jan  7 16:45:57.641 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Tue Jan  7 16:45:57.641 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Tue Jan  7 16:45:57.641 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Tue Jan  7 16:45:57.641 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Tue Jan  7 16:45:57.641 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: final commit...
Tue Jan  7 16:45:57.953 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: closing all files...
Tue Jan  7 16:45:58.024 [signalProcessingThread] closeAllFiles() finished
Tue Jan  7 16:45:58.024 [signalProcessingThread] journalCleanup...
Tue Jan  7 16:45:58.024 [signalProcessingThread] removeJournalFiles
Tue Jan  7 16:45:58.032 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Tue Jan  7 16:45:58.032 dbexit: really exiting now
```

You can see the query dumped in line 19 of that dump.

Thanks a lot for your time and let me know if there's any more info required.

---

### EDIT:

As requested, here's a var_dump() for `$voterId` and `$line`:

**$voterId**

```
string(18) "a0Qd0000001kMRwEAM"
```

**$line**

```
array(95) {
  [0]=>
  string(18) "a0ed0000000p75wAAA"
  [1]=>
  string(18) "005d00000010pc9AAA"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [3]=>
  string(16) "Phone- 000000000"
  [4]=>
  string(19) "2012-09-21 19:16:30"
  [5]=>
  string(18) "005d00000010pc9AAA"
  [6]=>
  string(19) "2012-09-21 19:16:30"
  [7]=>
  string(18) "005d00000010pc9AAA"
  [8]=>
  string(19) "2013-01-05 17:18:54"
  [9]=>
  string(0) ""
  [10]=>
  string(0) ""
  [11]=>
  string(0) ""
  [12]=>
  string(35) "Sample Question Text appears here !"
  [13]=>
  string(0) ""
  [14]=>
  string(0) ""
  [15]=>
  string(0) ""
  [16]=>
  string(0) ""
  [17]=>
  string(0) ""
  [18]=>
  string(0) ""
  [19]=>
  string(0) ""
  [20]=>
  string(0) ""
  [21]=>
  string(0) ""
  [22]=>
  string(0) ""
  [23]=>
  string(0) ""
  [24]=>
  string(0) ""
  [25]=>
  string(0) ""
  [26]=>
  string(0) ""
  [27]=>
  string(0) ""
  [28]=>
  string(0) ""
  [29]=>
  string(0) ""
  [30]=>
  string(0) ""
  [31]=>
  string(0) ""
  [32]=>
  string(0) ""
  [33]=>
  string(0) ""
  [34]=>
  string(0) ""
  [35]=>
  string(0) ""
  [36]=>
  string(0) ""
  [37]=>
  string(0) ""
  [38]=>
  string(0) ""
  [39]=>
  string(0) ""
  [40]=>
  string(0) ""
  [41]=>
  string(0) ""
  [42]=>
  string(0) ""
  [43]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [44]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [45]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [46]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [47]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [48]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [49]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [50]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [51]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [52]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [53]=>
  string(0) ""
  [54]=>
  string(0) ""
  [55]=>
  string(0) ""
  [56]=>
  string(9) "Undecided"
  [57]=>
  string(9) "Undecided"
  [58]=>
  string(9) "Undecided"
  [59]=>
  string(0) ""
  [60]=>
  string(0) ""
  [61]=>
  string(0) ""
  [62]=>
  string(0) ""
  [63]=>
  string(0) ""
  [64]=>
  string(0) ""
  [65]=>
  string(0) ""
  [66]=>
  string(0) ""
  [67]=>
  string(0) ""
  [68]=>
  string(0) ""
  [69]=>
  string(0) ""
  [70]=>
  string(0) ""
  [71]=>
  string(0) ""
  [72]=>
  string(0) ""
  [73]=>
  string(0) ""
  [74]=>
  string(0) ""
  [75]=>
  string(0) ""
  [76]=>
  string(0) ""
  [77]=>
  string(0) ""
  [78]=>
  string(0) ""
  [79]=>
  string(0) ""
  [80]=>
  string(0) ""
  [81]=>
  string(0) ""
  [82]=>
  string(0) ""
  [83]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [84]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [85]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [86]=>
  string(18) "a0Qd0000001kMRwEAM"
  [87]=>
  string(9) "Favorable"
  [88]=>
  string(0) ""
  [89]=>
  string(0) ""
  [90]=>
  string(0) ""
  [91]=>
  string(0) ""
  [92]=>
  string(0) ""
  [93]=>
  string(0) ""
  [94]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

And here's the system.indexes collection showing that the Id field is indeed indexed:

```
{ "v" : 1, "key" : { "_id" : 1 }, "ns" : "cavers-import.Voters", "name" : "_id_" }
{ "v" : 1, "key" : { "Id" : 1 }, "ns" : "cavers-import.Voters", "name" : "Id_1" }
```

Comment: what is $line an array or a string? It would be helpful to see the dump of $line

Comment: I would be surprised if voterid is indexed, since the output is saying nscanned: 816378

Comment: Updated my question with the info requested. $line is an array.

Comment: If your intent is to have each element of the $line array be an element in the PhoneCalls array then you need to also use $each with your $push. Is PhoneCalls an array already to begin with? The docs say if it isn't then the op will fail

Comment: No, the intention is for each $line to be an object within the `PhoneCalls` array of objects, so I don't want to use $each. Also, `PhoneCalls` shouldn't exist the first time a line is added to a voter, but then it should just be an array and the docs say: "If the field is absent in the document to update, $push adds the array field with the value as its element." so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. So, I don't believe that is going to work. You say you want $line to be an object, but it isn't an associative array. To my knowledge and you can check this out using json_encode, $line won't be an object, it will be an array, because it is not associative, and thus doesn't have key => value pairs. Further, integers aren't valid key names, so, $line will not be converted into a json object to be pushed.

Comment: It will work... just you wont have an object - it would be an array of arrays - couldn't fit that in my last comment

Comment: Yep, that makes sense, I got it all setup with your answer the way I wanted it though. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer is a simple one-too-many arrays around your query:

```
   $db->Voters->update(array(
        array(
            "Id" => $voterId
        )
    ), ...
```

Should actually be:

```
 $db->Voters->update(
    array(
        "Id" => $voterId
    ), ...
```

If I wrap the query in an additional set of brackets, as is the case in this problem, the mongo shell raises an error.

In the mongo shell your query would look like:

```
db.Voters.update({{Id: voterId}}, {update info here ...});
```

Which is not correct