# Read timed out after reading 0 bytes, waited for 30.000000 seconds in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

When I am working on above 5,000,000 records in mongodb, it shows this error `"Read timed out after reading 0 bytes, waited for 30.000000 seconds"` in `find()` query. Please any one help me.

Comment: When I search around it seems to be related to bugs like this one: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHP-922 , can you tell us something about when and how you get this error?

Comment: Also take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982761/mongodb-cursor-timeout-on-update it seems to be mostly PHP questions coming to light on this one

Comment: What driver version and MongoDB server version are you using? Also, are you connecting to a standalone server, replica set, or sharded cluster?

Answer (score 9):

In PHP you can set `timeout(-1)` to your cursor.

PHP Example:

```
$conn = new MongoClient("mongodb://primary:27017,secondary:27017", array("replicaSet" => "myReplSetName"));
$db = $conn->selectDB(DBname);
$collection = $db->selectCollection(collection);
$cursor = $collection->find();
$cursor->timeout(-1);
```

Node.js Example:

```
// Database connect options
var options = { replset: { socketOptions: { connectTimeoutMS : conf.dbTimeout }}};

// Establish Database connection
var conn = mongoose.connect(conf.dbURL, options);
```

Answer (score 4):

In PHP you could add the parameter socketTimeoutMS to the other parameters of connection string, in this case to 90 seconds.

```
$conn = new MongoClient("mongodb://primary:27017,secondary:27017", array("socketTimeoutMS" => "90000"));
```

Greetings!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the mongodb log file and find your query in it -- how long does it take to execute? If it does take a long time, have you added indexes? Are they being used?  Cut/paste the query from mongodb log file and try it from mongo shell -- and add ".explain()" at the end. It will tell you the execution plan that MongoDB is performing -- and perhaps you can attack your problem from that side.  If your queries really do take longer than 30 seconds, you most likely need to address it anyway -- regardless of the driver timeout issues.

Answer (score 2):

ensureIndex keys and try

```
MongoCursor::$timeout = 600000;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've spotted this problem on removing 1-2kk logs records using php driver.
Basically i had to add timeout (i'm using indexes, just db is a bit huge)

```
    $dtObject = new DateTime();
    $dtObject->modify("- " . $interval);
    $date = new MongoDate($dtObject->format("U"));
    $filter = array('dtCreated' => array('$lt' => $date));
    $num = $this->collection->count($filter);
    if ($num > 0)
        $this->collection->remove($filter)->timeout(-1);
    return $num;
```

This worked for me